# How do I resolve data duplication in a power query from a data model in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, datamodel

This seems like it must be simple to solve, but all the articles I can find are SQL based and I'm trying to resolve in the Excel data model but have encountered an early issue.

I have cut this right back to only having two tables for the moment, I do need to connect seven in the end, all have one to many relationships.

In the version I've cut down to I have two tables, shipments and production. The relationship is Many shipments to one production.

When I am using just fields from the Shipments app, the results are correct, see screen one, just showing the entries with data for the selected fields.

[image: Screen 1]

However when I add anything from the other table, see screen 2, here it's a unique code that appears of each of the production entries, then I get a duplication, so that I see an entry for each of the 8 production entries, for each of the 8 shipment entries with some data to show.

[image: Screen 2]

This sounds like a fan trap but there are only two tables, I really don't want to have to use a different data source, is this something simple I am missing?

I have already tried using different keys, removing any null values from the key fields I am using and starting from scratch but no luck.

The data is linked to the data model from local spreadsheets, the relationship appears with the * on  Shipments and and the 1 on the Production on the diagram view.

Screen with sum value field from the shipments app
[image]

Screen with sum value from the Production app
[image]

Screen with the relationships

[image]

Comment: You don't appear to have a data field in there - is that intentional?

Comment: Maybe post the diagram view and if you can, a link to the sample file.

Comment: @Rory not really deliberate, I just haven't got that far before encountering the error

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I have posted the diagram view at the end, not sure how to upload the  actual sample file here?

Comment: It's not really an error, unless it persists after you add a data field.

Comment: Is the final report fixed or do you need pivot tables to make it dynamic? you could possibly achieve what you're looking for directly in Power Query.

Comment: @Rory thanks for the advice, I have added some value fields now, I tried adding one from each table, adding one from the shipments table, which is the many side of the relationship, wrapped everything up together, and that is most likely where those values would come from. I also tried one from the other Production table, from the one side, and that gave the same today for each, so something is still causing confusion

Comment: @RicardoDiaz the pivot table is a means to an end, no need for it to be very dynamic, just there to join the data sources together, and also my users are used to that way of working, but if it can be done in power query that's worth a look, are there any training courses on that that you know of?

Comment: Miguel and Ken are the best [link](https://academy.powerquery.training/courses/power-query-academy). But also, post the final result you're looking for and as said, a link to sample workbook, and I can at least give you something to get you started

Comment: That's very generous @RicardoDiaz, wetransfer link is below, the files are: What I'm trying to achieve is shown in the "Overview Sales - Order Status" tab on the "Newlogistics tracker" sheet, this original is a pivot based on data in one flat tab, whereas I'm trying to get the same from multiple different tables. The "Orders" and "Shipments" sheets are data tables and "Beauty Data" is my data model. I also want to be able to create PowerBI dashboard from the same data model, but one problem at a time!

Comment: @RicardoDiaz the link to the file has been added to the question.

Comment: Hi @ChrisAllen what fields from each table should be output in the report? for example, first column after shipment status is order no, but I don't see that column in either of the source tables...

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz if we can start with these ones: Shipment status, Negotiated deadline, Backoffice Ref, Client, Brand, Product Type, Production Manager, then sum of these quantities: Total Pieces, Order Quantitym ITS Quantity+, QC SS Boat Quantity+, ITS Polybag Quantity+, Total Shipment Quantity+. There needs to be a subtotal for each production, you can add the Production ID there if needed. Not the whole list but that gives me some of each field type, so if that works should be able to take it from there

,=

Comment: @ChrisAllen take a look at [this file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArAKssDW3T7wnaFZcTOg2JkCvrYsRw?e=uV1nqI). Replace the file paths with yours, and refresh the report table (right click | refresh) Let me know if we are in the right path

Comment: @RicardoDiaz downloaded and changed the file paths, got an error on refresh "Query 'connShipments' (step 'Source') refers to other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination"

Comment: You can change the setting of privacy to "Always ignore privacy levels settings" see [this](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/07/04/data-privacy-settings-in-power-bipower-query-part-4-disabling-data-privacy-checks/)

Comment: That seems to be working, thanks @RicardoDiaz I'll have to work through my requirement from your example, I'm not as familiar with power queries so may take me a day or two, thanks for all your help. I'd still be interested to know what it was that stopped the pivot table idea from working, if that can be explained?

Comment: As Rory said and AFAIK, you need to add a data field so the Pivot Table can use the tables relationships.